# After pressing submit button a cursor stay certain input field

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm studying contact form.
It works fine. but When user click submit button, pages scroll middle of page and a cursor stay inside below input field.

> blade file

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label for="xx">test</label>
      <select id="xx" name="xx" class="form-control" onchange="showResult()"></select>
</div>
```

I can display bellow success message using below code.
However success message shows top of page so I can't see them.

```
<!-- Success message -->
@if(Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{Session::get('success')}}
    </div>
 @endif
```

> Here is head of form  tag

```
<form action="" method="post" action="{{ route('contact.store') }}">
```

Could you teach me how to fix problem?
I was thinking to put JavaScript code that goes top of page after clicking submit.
Could you teach me good way and code please?

Comment: delete extra `action=""`

Comment: Thank you. I delete that part. but still same problem.

Comment: @bluetail can you show me the showResult() function of javascript ?

Comment: Thank you everyone. I just figure out the cause. another input field has autofocus tag. I'm very sorry.